# Where can I find the list of SQLException error codes for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

`java.sql.SQLException` offers an `int getErrorCode()` function so the program can know what in particular has happened to cause the exception. Any chance to get a list of these codes for MySQL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They're available in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-handling.html).

- [Server error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html)
- [Client error codes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-client.html)